# Angular 8 - Create Lists of JSON Keys/values Returned from POST Request

Tags: json, angular, parsing, post, angular8

All I am trying to do is this:

> -get the "monthYear" from my JSON response -> set them to a list variable named **xValues**

> -get the "numSessionIds" from my JSON response -> set them to a list variable named **yValues**

My JSON response: (I added some new lines and spaces to make it easier to read in this post):

```
[
    {
        "monthYear": "Jan 20",
        "numSessionIds": 2,
        "monthInDateFormat": 1577768400000
    },
    {
        "monthYear": "Feb 20",
        "numSessionIds": 5,
        "monthInDateFormat": 1580446800000
    },
    {
        "monthYear": "Mar 20",
        "numSessionIds": 0,
        "monthInDateFormat": 1582952400000
    }
]
```

I get this data by calling this function in **chart.service.ts**:

```
httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       credentials: 'same-origin',
     }),
  };

callNumberOfSessionsSP():any{
    return this.http.post(`${this.BASE_URL}/RESTAPI/reports/callNumberOfSessionsSP?startDate=2020-01-01&endDate=2022-01-01&frequency=monthly`,
      this.httpOptions,{responseType: 'json', observe: 'response'}).subscribe()
  }
```

constructor & initial variable names (**chart.component.ts**):

```
  chartData: any;
  xValues: any;
  yValues: any;

  constructor(private chartService:ChartService) { }
```

my ngOnInit method (**chart.component.ts**):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.chartData = this.chartService.callNumberOfSessionsSP();

    this.xValues = ??????
    this.yValues = ??????
}
```

The ?????? is where I'm unsure what to put. **I've already tried things like:**

this.xValues= this.chartData.monthYear;

this.xValues= JSON.parse(Object.keys(this.chartData));

Comment: Are you sure you the api is of type POST? Coz you are appending the data as url parameter which is usually done in GET method type

Comment: I'm able to print values from the json response body in console.log. the api call went through without error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I created xValues and yValues lists from the JSON response:

**chart.component.ts:**

```
    xValues: string[] = [];
    yValues: number[] = [];

    constructor(private chartService: ChartService) {
        this.chartService.callNumberOfSessionsSP().subscribe((data: any) => {
            //console.log(data[0].monthYear);
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                console.log(data[i].monthYear);
                this.xValues.push(data[i].monthYear);
                this.yValues.push(data[i].numSessionIds);
            }
            



        console.log("printing this.xValues: ");
        console.log(this.xValues);

        console.log("printing this.yValues: ");
        console.log(this.yValues);

    }
```

**chart.service.ts:**

```
callNumberOfSessionsSP(): any {
        return this.http.post(`${this.BASE_URL}/RESTAPI/reports/callNumberOfSessionsSP?startDate=2021-01-01&endDate=2021-05-01&frequency=monthly`,
            this.httpOptions).pipe(
                map((data: []) => {
                    return data;
                }), catchError(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    return throwError('Error occurred while calling api of name "callNumberOfSessionsSP"');
                })
            )
    }
```

**Explanation**:

I basically just needed the below for loop to iterate through each JSON set of 3 values (monthYear, numSessionIds, monthInDateFormat) with the [i] index. This allowed me to do .monthYear and .numSessionIds to get specific columns / values of specific keys in the json response.

***Before I was trying data.monthYear, but I just needed to do data[i].monthYear.***

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].monthYear);
    this.xValues.push(data[i].monthYear);
    this.yValues.push(data[i].numSessionIds);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of POST

```
callNumberOfSessionsSP():any {
    const dataToPost = {startDate:'2020-01-01', endDate:'2022-01-01', frequency: 'monthly'}
    return this.http.post(`${this.BASE_URL}/RESTAPI/reports/callNumberOfSessionsSP`, dataToPost, this.httpOptions);
}
```

In case of GET

```
callNumberOfSessionsSP():any{
    return this.http.get(`${this.BASE_URL}/RESTAPI/reports/callNumberOfSessionsSP?startDate=2020-01-01&endDate=2022-01-01&frequency=monthly`, this.httpOptions);
}
```

In your chart.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.chartData = this.chartService.callNumberOfSessionsSP().subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data); /* <-- will have the whole response */
        this.xValues = data.map(a => a.monthYear); //--> ["Jan 20", "Feb 20", "Mar 20"]
        this.yValues = data.map(a => a.numSessionIds); //--> [2, 5, 0]
    });
}
```

Comment: that just prints it to the screen, I need the xvalues and the yvalues of the response to be put into 2 separate lists.

Comment: Doing that I get "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" in the console

Comment: @CollinFox Where did you use the .map function in your code?

Comment: I don't have a map function implemented I was thinking it would use a built in one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230568/discussion-between-zam-abdul-vahid-and-collin-fox).